# Skip to the next iteration if it takes to much time c#

Tags: c#, loops, timer, ip, ping

I want to ping from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255

So I use

```
FOR(i=1;i<=255;i++)

 //each time, I test the IP address by pinging it with the following code

try {

 PingReply reply = pinger.Send(AdresaIp);
 pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;

}

 catch (PingException)

 {

  // Discard PingExceptions and return false;

 }
```

The problem that I encounter is at:

```
PingReply reply = pinger.Send(AdresaIp);

pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

When the ping succeeds the two line from above have an execution time of 2 milliseconds, but when it fails(witch will happen multiple times) it takes about 3 seconds, witch is HUGE if I ping 255 IPs.

So I want to implement a timer in the following manner:

```
    if (timer > 1 second) continue; 
    //if it takes more than 1 second for the current iteration jump to the next
```

iteration.

I tryed the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew(`) ,doesen't work for me, because it gives me the time AFTER the ping is tested.
I need something that allows me to check WHILE the ping test works, so in the moment when it reaches 1 second I can use the CONTINUE command.

Thanks,

Vlad

Comment: What is the type of `pinger`?

Comment: Ping pinger = new Ping();

Comment: You may also want to consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use [Ping.Send Method (IPAddress, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf697k33(v=vs.110).aspx)
. The second parameter is a timeout:

> timeout
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> An Int32 value that specifies the maximum number of milliseconds (after sending the echo message) to wait for the ICMP echo reply message.

Comment: Thank you,  I just needed to add " ,1000 "  :D